# Label observations using a variable in plot using SAS

Tags: sas

I am doing a simple linear regression as shown below.

```
data test;
    input name $ x y;
    datalines;
    A 1   0.45
    B 0.9 0.1
    C 0.8 0.34
    D 0.7 0.58
    E 0.6 0.7
    F 0.5 0.57
    G 0.4 0.55
    H 0.3 0.44
    ;
run;

proc reg data=test;
    model y=x;
run;
```

I was given the following plots. Is it possible to label those dots using the `name` variable in the original data set? In other words, I want to put "A", "B", ... near those dots.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm not sure there's a trivial solution for you.

First off, you can add the `ID` statement in order to tell SAS that the `name` variable is your "ID" variable.

```
proc reg data=test;
    model y=x;
    ID name;
run;
```

Second, you can tell specific plots to display labels - subject to those plots listening (i.e., the plots only display certain labels by default.  Remember, these are programmed to work for large datasets as well as small - so 1000 labels would make the plot unreadable.)

```
proc reg data=test plots=diagnostics(label);
    model y=x;
    ID name;
run;
```

This displays "B" on the diagnostic plot - because "B" is an "influential" observation.

You can use the `annotate` option to add specific annotations; that can be very challenging, though there is some information out there.  The best source is Art Carpenter's *Guide to Innovative SAS Techniques*, which is a book available from SAS press.

Finally, you can make many (if not all?) of these plots yourself in `PROC SGPLOT` or similar.  That will give you a lot more flexibility as far as labels and annotations - at the cost of having to write more code to do it.